# Vim search and delete (:g/string/d) but that asks permission?

Tags: vim, full-text-search, replace

Basically I want to mass-delete strings, but don't trust my attention span enough to not confirm each one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do `:%s/.*string.*\n//gc` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/foo//gc`

but you could have gogled that yourself... http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: That removes the content, but does not delete the line. it turns `foo bar` into `bar`. I need the equivalent of the `dd` command.

Comment: the very title of the question implies that, as g//d deletes lines…

Answer (score -1):

This command will, I believe, delete any line containing the "foo" string:

```
:g/foo/d
```